# WSO2 ESB won't forward a multi-part file to a proxy service

Tags: java, proxy, wso2, esb, multipart

**Background:**
    I have a spring based REST web-service that receives a less than 1k xml file and after processing it, posts a message to a Topic running on ActiveMQ. Application war is deployed to a Tomcat instance and everything works like a charm and I receive a Http 201 (created) response. Then I created a simple WSO2 ESB Proxy Service which using Pass-through protocol sends the same message to REST service deployed on Tomcat. This works as expected on my local machine and I get a Http 201 (created).

**Issue:**
    When proxy service is deployed on a remote WSO2 ESB instance, within the same network, I start getting Http 202 (Accepted) response as compared to 201 (Created). This issue is only for REST service that has a multipart request param. I am able to pass couple of params to another REST web-service with no issues. I have used RestTemplate and AdvancedRestClient (Chrome plugin) to submit messages.

**My Configuration:**

- WSO2 ESB: 4.7.0
- Tomcat: 7.0.42
- Oracle: JDK 1.7.0_45
- ActiveMQ: 5.8.0
- OS: Debian Sqeeze

**Troubleshooting steps:**
    Set log level to DEBUG for each entry in `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/conf/log4.properties, nothing significant pointing to the issue
    Installed Tomcat and ActiveMQ on same remote machine containing WSO2 ESB, posted directly against remote Tomcat and received a Http 201 as expected

Here is my proxy definition at `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/EventProxy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="EventProxy"
   transports="http"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="enable">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8080/services/event"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Tried following properties under inSequence in my proxy but to no success.

- `<property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
  />`
- `<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>`
- Changed Tomcat listening port to be 9000 and in service proxy file
- Disabled Filter mediator in main sequence
  `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml
- Added `<drop/>` mediator after send in inSequence at
  `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml

Is there any external setting (increasing some sort of timeout) that I need to do when running on remote server ? I am new to WSO2 and ran out of ideas so any helpful pointers will be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Steps performed:**

Changed `<Host>` element in `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/conf/carbon.xml by using DNS name and also IP but similar 202 response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of debugging, log levels, tcpdump and wireshark, reminded me of make file space issue, apparently my test client was submitting a url with a space at the end and WSO2 was responding back with a 202 for that, once it was discovered and space at end was removed, everything worked as expected.

Disappointed on myself but also on wso2 esb for not responding correctly, it should have responded like 'can't find the proxy service' or something like that.